# how to go with the database connection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to create a login page for authenticating users.But i'm new to angularjs and not understanding how to have connection with database and how to go with it.kindly help me with this.

Comment: AngularJS will be your front end... What do you have on server-side?

Comment: php can be used for the backend

Comment: So you would call a rest Api from AngularJS... Php will host this rest API which will then connect to DB to get the data...

Comment: okay ill try this

Comment: I would go with Google Firebase. You will not need any server side code and can set any authentication method that you like such as email/password, facebook, twitter, github etc

Comment: This link has your answer https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! This is my solution with Google Firebase Authentication if you decide to give it a try! The first thing you need to do is [sign up for a free Firebase account](https://firebase.google.com/).

1.Create a new project.

2.Click on the Authentication menu.

3.In the SIGN-IN METHOD tab Enable Email/Password.

4.Customize e-mail messages (to confirm registration and change password) sent by the Firebase App in the E-MAIL TEMPLATES tab.

6.Go to your console home and click in the "Add Firebase to your web app" icon on the Overview section. Copy and paste the code into the **index.html** page in order to **Initialize the Firebase SDK**.

On your **index.html** file you need to add Firebase and AngularFire js files, like this:

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>

<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

After the closing body tag (still in your **index.html** file), **initialize the Firebase SDK**:

```
<script>
// Initialize the Firebase SDK
var config = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

On your login view:

```
<form name="register" ng-submit="createUser()" novalidate>
<input type="text" name"email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true">
<input type="text" name"password" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
<p>{{ message }}</p>
<p>{{ error }}</p>
</form>
```

On your controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','firebase']);

app.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth) {

    var auth = $firebaseAuth();

    // to create a user
    $scope.createUser = function() {        
        auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
            $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error.message;
        });
    };

    // to log a user
    $scope.logUser = function() {  
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
            if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
                $location.path('/success');
            } else {
                $scope.message = "Wrong user name or password";
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Detailed answer for firebase onboarding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, `Angular` or front-end (client-side) web frameworks are not supposed to talk to `Sql Server` or Backend server directly. We need server framework like `ASP.Net Web API` on IIS, `ExpressJs` on `NodeJS` server that can orchestrate the requests from client-side web application to backend server.

It is mandatory to have a web server unless you want to store the data in `Firebase`.